# How to stop OpenGL background bleed on transparent textures

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, transparency

I have an iOS OpenGL ES 2.0 3D game and am working to get transparent textures working nicely, in this particular example for a fence.

I'll start with the final result. The bits of green background/clear color are coming through around the edges of the fence - note how it isn't ALL edges and some of it is ok:

[image: Background bleed evidence]

The reason for the lack of bleed in the top right is order of operations. As you can see from the following shots, the order of draw includes some buildings that get drawn BEFORE the fence. But most of it is after the fence:

[image: Draw progression with depth]

So one solution is to always draw my transparent textured objects last. I would like to explore other solutions, as my pipeline might not always allow this. I'm looking for other suggestions to solve this problem without sorting my draws.

This is likely a depth or blend function, but i've tried a ton of stuff and nothing seems to work (different blend functions, different discard alpha levels, different background colors, different texture settings).

Here are some specifics of my implementation.

In my frag shader I'm throwing out fragments that have transparency - this way they won't render to depth:

```
lowp vec4 texVal = texture2D(sTexture, texCoord);
if(texVal.w < 0.5)
    discard;
```

I'm using one giant PVR texture atlas with mipmapping - the texture itself SHOULD just have 0 or 1 for alpha, but something with the blending could be causing this:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

I'm using the following blending when rendering:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Any suggestions to fix this bleed would be great!

EDIT - tried a different min filter for the texture as suggested in the comments, LINEAR/NEAREST, but same result. Note I have also tried NEAREST/NEAREST and no luck:

[image]

Comment: Try nearest neighbour in your mipmap. GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST

Comment: Thanks - just tried that one with same result. I had tried a few others previously but same or similar results.

Comment: Can you try something; rather than discard, return a transparent colour (0,0,0,0) for the fragment.

Comment: Good suggestion - the issue with that is those fragments will be rendered to the depth buffer, causing things drawn after the fence to not even be passed to the fragment shader. Tried it, but then I end up with almost exclusively green behind the fence.

Comment: Have you disabled (completely - driver control panel) Anti-Aliasing?

Comment: I'm not sure about disabling anti-aliasing. I don't think I have it enabled - I'm not using a glRenderbufferStorageMultisampleAPPLE call or anything like that. Can you point me to something specific to check?

Comment: transparency is a difficult problem in complex scenes and i dont think there is much you can do other than getting the draw order right. http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting

Comment: I'd suggest keeping linear texture sampling and the discard but then set texVal.w = 1.0, although a final rendering pass with sorted semi-transparent objects would probably give better results.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Draw order is for sure a fool proof solution. Regarding the texVal.w=1.0, what should that achieve? I tried that (when not discard) and it didn't change anything.

Comment: For the time being I've mostly solved the issue by changing the background to all black (alpha=1). The artifacts are still there but very much reduced, hardly noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

try increasing the alpha filter limit,

`lowp vec4 texVal = texture2D(sTexture, texCoord);
if(texVal.w < 0.9)
    discard;`

Comment: I tried this before - it does mostly eliminate the color bleed through. However, it also makes it so I can't really see the grates on the fence anymore, it looks like its not there unless I get really close then I just see glimmers of it. You're clearly on to something...  the original texture *should* only have values of 0.0 and 1.0 for alpha, so something is blending things, likely the linear filtering...  any other ideas or explanation as to why?

Comment: because when you start rendering the fence, the only color it sees is the glClearColor when it tries to calculate the blend function.

Comment: you can try to comment out glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT), so the SRC_ALPHA will be the previous buffer.

Comment: Your explanation isn't making sense to me unfortunately. I tried your suggestion too, and things are unchanged. I still don't understand why the EDGES of the fence is where the background is bleeding. It seems obvious that since I'm not sorting the objects, when I try to draw the buildings between the background and the fence those EDGES are failing the depth test, but I really don't think they should be (given I only have 1.0 or 0.0 as alpha, so the 0.0s should be discarded and not added to the depth buffer).

Comment: The fact that if you increase the alpha filter limit, the color bleed was eliminated means that your alpha isn't just 0 or 1(LINEAR filtering on texture2D). The supposedly transparent fragments gains depth (because depth writing is enabled), it then calculates the blend function (glBlendFunc) using the current available colors(the ones that are already rendered + green clear color). When the buildings behind the fence are rendered, the fragments get discarded because those green fragments has depth.

Comment: This makes sense. So do you think there are actually values in my PNG/PVR texture files that have a alpha that is not 0 or 1? Or more likely you suspect something is being blended. The way I see it if the rendering happens in one pixel like a) clear, depth = 1.0, b) fence hole, depth = 0.5 (this should get discarded), c) building, depth = 0.75, because b) was discarded the c) should get drawn. But if the alpha of b) was actually > 0.5/0.9 the depth is filled in and its not drawn. Any thoughts on how can I check for or eliminate these 0<a<1 alpha values?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I came across it several times whilst trying to find an answer to my very similar OpenGL issue. Thought I'd share my findings here for anyone with similar. The culprit in my code looked like this:

```
glClearColor(1, 0, 1, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

I used a pink transparent colour for ease of visual reference whilst debugging. Despite the fact it was transparent when it was blending between background and the colour of the subject it would bleed in much like the symptoms in the screenshot of the question. What fixed it for me was wrapping this code to mask the glClear step. It looked like this:

```
glColorMask(false, false, false, true);
glClearColor(1, 0, 1, 0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColorMask(true, true, true, true);
```

To my knowledge, this means when the clear process kicks in it only operates on the alpha channel. After this is was all re-enabled to continue the process as intended. If someone with a more solid knowledge of OpenGL can explain it better I'd love to hear!

Comment: This doesn't work for me and actually it shouldn't as the color buffer just left filled by a garbage. I believe it has something with OpenGL context settings as I have this artefacts even when blending is disabled but multisampling is enabled. So during multisampling renderer blends with the current RGB values ignoring the fact that alpha is zero...