# Transparent faces causing faces behind them to disappear

Tags: vb.net, opengl, 3d, transparency, opentk

I'm programming a game with the .NET library OpenTK. I'm trying to create a fog effect near certain areas by drawing a series of transparent faces. However, the faces turn everything behind them to the sky color, as seen at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/97311769/texglitch.png

Is there any way to stop this from happening, or a better way to create this fog effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314180/how-to-stop-opengl-background-bleed-on-transparent-textures) might be relevant to your problem. Transparency can be a tricky task in 3d graphics rendering.

Also, if you are using OpenGL 2.0+ a better way to do fog would be to get hold of the depth buffer, and in a shader, depending on how 'far away' the fragment is, you blend the fragment with the colour of your fog colour.

Comment: Thanks! Now the only problem is it has some weird striping occasionally, but that's probably just overlapping with other 'fog areas'.